# creating standard tiles with background image from internet

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to create a standarttile with background image from direct website,

and what I do is fine in wp8,
but the same code do not work in wp7

here is the code below:

```
void setTile(string title, string IconPath1x1, string IconPath2x2,
             string IconPath4x2, string IconPath2x2Back, string IconPath4x2Back,
             string wideContent, string targetUri)
{
    StandardTileData Standarddata = new StandardTileData()
    {
            //IconPath2x2 = "http://i.imgur.com/something.png"
            Title = title + "_",
            BackgroundImage = new Uri(IconPath2x2, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),

            BackContent = "",
            BackTitle = title + "_",

            BackBackgroundImage = new Uri(IconPath1x1, UriKind.Absolute)
    };

    ShellTile tiletopin = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(
                          x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains(targetUri));

    if (tiletopin == null)
    {
        ShellTile.Create(
            new Uri(targetUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), Standarddata);
    }
}
```

I have tried this link, but it didn't work

http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/03/20/windows-phone-7-bringing-your-application-tile-to-life/

do I miss something or it doesn't work in wp7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll need to download the image and save it locally. You can then refer to the image from isolated storage

```
string fileName = @"Shared\ShellContent\backgroundTileImage.jpg";
if(TrySaveImage(fileName, "http://foo.com/bar.png"))
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("isostore:/" + fileName, UriKind.Absolute);
    // Create the tile if we didn't find it already exists.
    var tileData = new StandardTileData
    {
        Title = "My Tile",
        BackgroundImage = uri,
    };
}

...
private bool TrySaveImage(string fileName, string url)
{
    using (var store = System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        try
        {
            var backImage = new Image();
            backImage.Height = backImage.Width = 173;
            backImage.Stretch = Stretch.None;
            backImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
            backImage.Measure(new Size(173, 173));
            backImage.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 173, 173));
            var image = new WriteableBitmap(backImage, null);

            string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
            if (!store.DirectoryExists(directory))
            {
                store.CreateDirectory(directory);
            }
            using (var stream = store.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                image.SaveJpeg(stream, 173, 173, 0, 100);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```